# Optimizing Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project where I need to export product sold report in Excel format. I am using [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

I have three Model.

**product.php**

```
class products extends Model
{
    protected $table='products';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable  = ['image', 'asin','price','strategy_id'];

    public function orderDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(order_details::class, 'SKU', 'asin');
    }

}
```

**orders.php**

```
class orders extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'orders';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id','date','quantity','totalAmount'];

    public function orderDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(order_details::class);
    }
}
```

**order_details.php**

```
class order_details extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_details';

    protected $fillable = ['id','order_id','SKU','unitPrice','quantity','totalPrice'];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(orders::class);
    }
```

Now I want to calculate how many time the each product sol in the last 30 days, 60 days and 90 days.

**Points to note**

1. products.asin = order_detils.SKU
2. The order_detail table does not have order date column.
3. One order can have many products with quantity more than 1.

My current query is:-

```
$products = products::query();

// Some where clauses/filters

$products = $products->get();

foreach($products as $product)
{
    // Getting the order_details which has this product
    $orderIds = order_details::where('SKU','=',$product->asin)->pluck('order_id');

    $product->sales30days = orders::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(30), Carbon::now()])->sum('quantity');
    $product->sales60days = orders::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(60), Carbon::now()])->sum('quantity');
    $product->sales90days = orders::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(90), Carbon::now()])->sum('quantity');
    $product->sales120days = orders::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::now()->subDays(120), Carbon::now()])->sum('quantity');
    $product->totalSold = orders::whereIn('id', $orderIds)->sum('quantity');
}
```

The above query is giving me the results I need, but is taking a lot of time and is not performance friendly. I have more than 100k products.

1. I there any solution to optimize this query?
2. Can I add pagination like `$products->paginate(100)` after this foreach loop?

Comment: I commented on one of the answers. Your starting point can be better. You are starting with getting all the products. Instead start with orders that's `date <= 120 days`. You won't need all these products. You will get the "only" product's which are in the orders that are `date <= 120 days`. It will be filtered version on data layer. Then you can iterate them on application layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are making MANY queries and it will inevitably be slow. This solution should have considerably better performance, since you only make two queries.

```
$orders = orders::with(['orderDetails'])->get();
$now = Carbon::now();
$quantities = [];

foreach($orders as $order) {
    $daysOld = $order->date->diffInDays($now);

    foreach ($order->orderDetails as $details) {
        if (!isset($quantities[$details->SKU])) {
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['30'] = 0;
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['60'] = 0;
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['90'] = 0;
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['120'] = 0;
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['total'] = 0;
        }

        if ($daysOld <= 30) {
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['30'] += $details->quantity;
        }

        if ($daysOld <= 60) {
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['60'] += $details->quantity;
        }
        
        if ($daysOld <= 90) {
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['90'] += $details->quantity;
        }

        if ($daysOld <= 120) {
            $quantities[$details->SKU]['120'] += $details->quantity;
        }

        $quantities[$details->SKU]['total'] += $details->quantity;
    }
}

return products::all()->map(function ($product) use ($quantities) {
    $product->sales30days  = $quantities[$product->asin]['30'];
    $product->sales60days  = $quantities[$product->asin]['60'];
    $product->sales90days  = $quantities[$product->asin]['90'];
    $product->sales120days = $quantities[$product->asin]['120'];
    $product->salesTotal   = $quantities[$product->asin]['total'];

    return $product;
});
```